# Paypal integration: Please return to the payment page and correct the address

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I'm trying to do a payment on my web with a VISA card and when i press Pay i get this error:
Please return to the payment page and correct the address.

Debug of input hidden values:

```
cmd->_hosted-payment
subtotal->0.6
business->--deleted--
currency_code->GBP
template->templateD
billing_first_name->Fulanito
billing_last_name->Benganito
billing_address1->Pepito Nº 14
billing_city->Temple (Vinewood)
billing_zip->29013
billing_country->Spain
lc->US
```

Any idea?
Thanks, regards.

Comment: Can you try with a different address, without the "º" character in it and see if that works?

Comment: This doesnt matter, i think that is the country problem, im testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I should post country as 'ES' instead of 'Spain'.